# Insert geo-coordinate in database, from google map address

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

i'm working with php & mysql i want to save the address in database as geo-coordinate using google maps

can you helpe me please with un exemple?

th'x all

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Querying Google maps with PHP? Storing the result in your database? What have you tried? What has failed? Please provide context and intent.

Comment: for exemple i want to insert my geo-goordinate in the data base how can i do? i have use a manualy input using this this exemple of google map.
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html

i'm looking if the is a why to save direct the geo-coordinate after the user put his address

Answer (score 2):

There are some excellent tutorials on google maps on the [google developers site](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/) ... here is the one you should have a look at [Creating a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch)